# Troubleshooting WCF Client Latency

Tags: c#, wcf

.NET 4.5.1

We have a web service that has a WCF client (generated from a WSDL). We see in our tracing that we enter a web service method call and then 2 min. later we exit that method.

That lead us to believe that the web service was causing issues. However we created a packet capture and found out that it was actually 2 minute after our request hit the wire.

Given that the generated WCF client is a black box of generated code. How could we go about identifying why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Put debugger and debug your client and WCF service both.

Comment: We can only reproduce this under heavy load. Which is very difficult to spoof with a loadui tool or something like that. Therefore I cannot use a debugger in prod.